# Can we show custom tooltip in over Highchart Dumbell circle not on the line

Tags: highcharts

I want to show  Custom tooltip over the circle(point not on the line for Highchart dumbell chart )
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJeG7.png

Here in image we can see tooltip is sowing for line but we want for custom point that we have created(Red)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a dummy series that will render this point and define a tooltip format by using the `tooltip.pointFormatter` callback.

```
  series: [{
    data: data
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    data: [{
      x: 1,
      y: 74
    }],
    color: 'red',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
        },
        showInLegend: false,
    tooltip: {
      pointFormatter() {
        return 'custom tooltip'
      }
    }
  }]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fmq8tL0n/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.tooltip.pointFormatter

Comment: Can we add this within multiple point and dynamic data over maker over?
Please help on that part too.

Comment: @ThakurlalPandey I do not sure if I understand your requirement... Could you reproduce this scenario on some online editor?